# SVG pattern through Javascript controlled sliders

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to design an SVG pattern and control its elements with sliders and radio buttons. My pattern is flowers positioned diagonally. I want to control the size of the circle inside the flower, number of petals and the length of petals. I would also like to have 2 jitter buttons so that user can randomize circles's sizes (flowers become different from each other) and number of petals. 
I've tried 4 separate files HTML, JS, CSS and SVG. It seems, the browser couldn't manage separate DOM trees. Now I'm trying with inline SVG and JS. So far the beginning of my pattern works, but I can't connect it with sliders. PLEASE help

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Pattern editor">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,SVG,JavaScript">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body onload="refresh()">
    <h1>Create your own pattern</h1>
      <div id="frame">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="500" height="500" stroke="black"fill="url(#pattern)"/>
      </div>
      <div>Cicle size: <input id="slider1" type="range" min="3" max="30" onchange="refresh()"/></div>
      <div>Number of petals: <input id="slider2" type="range" min="1" max="60" onchange="refresh()"/></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh(){
      var pattern;
      var slider1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("slider1").value);



      pattern = '<svg width="600" height="600">
      x="20" y="10" width="140" height="140"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        patternTransform="rotate(45)">
       <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="slider1" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
      </svg>';
      document.getElementById("frame").innerHTML = pattern;
    }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/recent/sliderzoom.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code.

```
pattern = '<svg width="600" height="600">
      x="20" y="10" width="140" height="140"
        patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        patternTransform="rotate(45)">
       <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="slider1" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
      </svg>';
```

You cannot do this in javascript because the string gets cut off after a line-break. To continue the string either concatenate them like `'str1' + 'str2'` or escape the line-break with `\`.

`<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="slider1" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>`

To set the value of `r` to a dynamic value of `slider1` you need to exclude it from the string. `r="' + slider1 + '"` should to the trick.

On another note, you can simply create the entire svg as static in your html and then change the value of specific pattern elements via javascript.

```
<svg width="600" height="600">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="pattern" x="20" y="10" width="140" height="140" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)">
        <circle id="circleP" cx="30" cy="30" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="500" height="500" stroke="black" fill="url(#pattern)" />
  </svg>
```

Then you can access the circle inside of the pattern with `getElementById` and change its radius with `setAttribute("r", value)`.

Link to a plunkr preview: http://embed.plnkr.co/BBsopyIjV5ae84W0PaSU/preview

Comment: Thank you very much. It answers quite a few of my questions and problems. It is extremely valuable advice to me at this stage as I struggle to understand how JS works in the first place.

Comment: I can’t thank you enough for your help. It works! It works!!!
I knew I was not far off, just going round and round in circles. I found JS baffling. It’s supposed to be easy. I like that you put JS separately – nice and clean structure. I'm working on petals now. I think it needs nested pattern and see-through outer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a very nice flowery pattern going. The size of centre circle changes by user moving the slider. In the same way petals change. I went down an easy way making them like intersecting star shape. I’m working now to get a button working for randomising size of circles. To be honest don’t know if it’s even possible. You can see it here: http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~abp4d9/